# if statement returns both if and else if at same time?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, return-value

I'm trying to write a code that randomizes a number (1 - 100), then prints all the odd numbers from 40 to that one. If the number is smaller than 40 it should print all the numbers up to the randomized one.

i.e. if the number is 45, it should print 41, 43, 45. And if it's 5 it should print 1,2,3,4,5.

My code below works until I add the `else if` statement. When I add this if the number is above 40 it still includes all numbers from 0 to 40? I don't understand why as I thought `if` statements should go one way or another not both?

Any ideas help on how to solve this, or what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
function myFunc() {

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var counter = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (i > 40 && i % 2 == 1) {
        counter.push(i);
    } else if (i < 40) {
        counter.push(i);
    }
}

return counter + ',' + x;

}

console.log(myFunc())
```

Comment: In the loop the variable `i` starts from 0 and goes up to `x`. If `x > 40` the loop will still iterate `i` from 0 to 40 and then up to `x`. What is not clear to you? Maybe you wanted to check for `x > 40` or ○x < 40`? Anyway be aware that using this type of cases excludes the possibility in which `x is 40`!

Comment: Nowhere in your loop are you checking for `x < 40`. You'll need to check it to determine what you want your loop to do for each `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new variable that checks where to start from. That way you can shorten the conditional in the loop too.

```
function myFunc() {

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var counter = [];
  var start = x >= 40 ? 40 : 0; // new variable

  for (var i = start; i < x; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) { counter.push(i); }
  }
  return counter + ',' + x;
}

console.log(myFunc())
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. There's one thing I don't understand. Why does the variable `start` here only work with the ternary operator not with an if..else statement? I understood them to be the same thing, only with a different syntax?

Comment: No problem. Should probably mark it as best answer in that case :). It will work with an if...then, but it depends how you're declaring it I guess. `if (x >= 40) { var start = 40; } else { var start = 0; }`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah yes that's it and it does work both ways, My mistake. How do I mark  as best answer on here? Forgive the ignorance, new to the site.

Comment: @moonshineOutlaw, there should be a tick mark next to my answer. Click it and it will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

you write not correct conditional:

```
else if (i < 40)
```

this statement is run, because first statement is false and i in progress 1,2,3,4,
you must change second statement to x < 40

```
function myFunc() {

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var counter = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (i > 40 && i % 2 == 1) {
        counter.push(i);
    } else if (x <= 40) { // only when x <= 40
        counter.push(i);
    }
}

return counter + ',' + x;

}

console.log(myFunc())
```